# How to display UIlabel with string format when selecting data from a UIPickerview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uipickerview

> Hi I have one picker view. This picker view from web services  came
>   to  loading data. This picker view is 2 part.  Picker view 1. part is 
>   Project name. and Picker view 2. part is Project number. When open
>   screen Project no label is no data. when open screen Project name
>   label no data. But when i rotate my picker view came to data this like
>   Proje Adı: "A1 Unitesi" Proje No: "002". How i can When open screen
>   came to data like rotate my picker ?
>
> When open screen Project Name and Project No Labels no data. I want
>   to came data when open screen

[image]

> When I rotate picker view came to data like this.

[image]

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
        return 2;
    }

    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {

        if (component == 0) {
            return [RaporlarList count];
        }
        return [RaporlarList count];

    }

    #pragma mark Picker Delegate Methods
    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {

        if (component == 0) {
        eObje =  [RaporlarList objectAtIndex:row];
        return  eObje.ProjeAdii;

        }
        eObje = [RaporlarList objectAtIndex:row];
        return eObje.ProjeNoo;
    }

    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark PickerView Delegate

    -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {

         if (component == 0)
{

    NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Proje Adı : %@", [[RaporlarList objectAtIndex:row] ProjeAdii]];
    lblProjeAdi.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", resultString];

}
else
{
    NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Proje No: %@", [[RaporlarList objectAtIndex:row] ProjeNoo]];
    lblProjeNo.text = resultString;

}

       }
```

Comment: You can't simply post a bunch of code with no explanation or even a question. Update your question with some relevant details about what issue you are having.

Comment: I am sorry Maddy. I forgot description about my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have selected wrong datasource for pickerview.

You are returning string, instead return the label

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

        // return your UILabel
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kunal. But what ı write code this part - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   if(row == 0 || row == 2)
}

Comment: create a UILabel object lets say 'returnLabel' and then call [returnLabel setText:eObje] adjust your frame accordingly.

Comment: Hi Kunal How are you ? Can you help to me please ? I share picture about my problem and i explanation about my problem ?

Comment: @Serdar I don't completely understand you problem ? Would you elaborate more on what you need.

Comment: if (component == 0)
    {
        NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Proje Adı : %@", [[RaporlarList objectAtIndex:row] ProjeAdii]];
        lblProjeAdi.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", resultString];

    }
    else
    {
        NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Proje No: %@", [[RaporlarList objectAtIndex:row] ProjeNoo]];
        lblProjeNo.text = resultString;

    } 
My problem solved With the above code

Comment: Hi Kunal Belani my another problem is How to display UIlabel with string format when page is opened? I explanation on picture my problem. I solved pass time problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

> The correct answer to my question is as follows:

```
  -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
        {

             if (component == 0)
    {

        NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Proje Adı : %@", [[RaporlarList objectAtIndex:row] ProjeAdii]];
        lblProjeAdi.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", resultString];

    }
    else
    {
        NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Proje No: %@", [[RaporlarList objectAtIndex:row] ProjeNoo]];
        lblProjeNo.text = resultString;

    }

           }
```